# How to make camera capture faster in react-native-camera?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-camera

```
  takePicture = async function() {
    if (this.camera) {

       const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true, pauseAfterCapture: true };
       const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);

        this.setState({path: data.uri});

    }   
  }
```

`takePicture` is my function to click the image. When I don't use `pauseAfterCapture` in options, then it takes 3 seconds for the image to get captured, while camera is still active in those 3 seconds. And when I use `pauseAfterCapture` it takes me around 1.5 seconds to capture image with the camera being active during those 1.5 seconds.

I've also used `skipProcessing` which helps me with fast capture but I don't want to lose other information like base64, width, quality, mirrorImage, exif, etc like mentioned on `react-native-camera` github page.

Is this has something to do with `takePictureAsync` taking time to resolve? If yes, then how do I manage it?

Also, if this question has no solution, how can I use *ActivityIndicator* when the image is getting captured.

P.S. - I know this question has been asked a lot but I'm unable to find any solution for this. I hope we all can come up with a solution so that it can help other people in future.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?